# Forget second input in action when prompt for first input is responsed

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have my code in following structure:

```
action(app){

//two inputs in this action
1.InvocationName
2.MenuOptionValue //(Action1,Action2,Action3)

//output
 Selected Menu Option operation

}
```

I am new to Bixby , I have following Two Questions:

1.When I give directly only menu option(2nd Input), it prompts me for Invocation name(1st Input) which is trained in NL ,and then I give invocation name and it starts output operation,which it should .But, here I want it to forget the previous Menu Option (2nd input) and prompt me for it again.Is it possible in this structure or suggest if possible in other structure way.

2.MenuOption have 3 options(Action1,Action2,Action3) which should redirect to 3 different operation on input.
Though i am printing in js (endpoint) on different inputs.But how will i perform another following action(User Interaction with Bixby) for those operation,saving previous data.Is it possible by this structure or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For question #1, please give concrete example. I don't understand what you want to do here. I will update my answer when you provide more content. Maybe as answer to question #2, remodeling your capsule to three actions each with different input solves this issue as well. Action would be isolated from each other, so there is no **remember** or **forget** issue.

For question #2, if 3 different actions requires different input method, for example, one is integer, and one is string or maybe the third is an integer plus string, you should consider make them different actions and link to separate JS file in endpoints. Then you can treat each action differently by adding different follow-up. Make sure you add training utterances for each of the actions. It is recommended that one action model in Bixby should handle, well, one action only.